# Scipy: pickle an ode solver instance

Tags: python, scipy, pickle, ode

I am running long simulations which involve integration of an ode. Due to the long running times, I decided to generate fallbacks which allow to continue the simulations from a checkpoint. For the ode integration, I decided to pickle the [scipy ode solver](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html) instance. This approach works for the reentrant solvers 'dopri5' and 'dop853', but fails for 'vode' and 'lsoda'. For my particular problem the 'vode' algo seems the fastest, so I am interested, whether one could circumvent this problem. I would expect that this is possible,
 because in a restart also only one solver instance is required.

Running the following two code snippets demonstrates my problem, check out this [gist](https://gist.github.com/pfeffer90/d72da2dae55b2d85890f94b99a69e6ba):

**initialize.py**

Starts an integration and persists the ode solver instance via pickling (using dill which can also pickle lambdas).

```
import scipy.integrate
import dill

# Solve a simple ode up to some time t
rhs= lambda t, y: -y
ode_solver = scipy.integrate.ode(rhs).set_integrator('vode')
ode_solver.set_initial_value(1)
ode_solver.integrate(1)
print ode_solver.t, ode_solver.y

## Stop solving and persist ode solver to a file
file_name='ode_instance.pkl'
with open(file_name, "w") as ode_file:
    dill.dump(ode_solver, ode_file)
```

**continue.py**

Tries to continue the above integration via loading the ode solver.

```
import scipy.integrate
import dill

## Restart the ode solver
file_name='ode_instance.pkl'
with open(file_name, "r") as ode_file:
    ode_solver = dill.load(ode_file)

ode_solver.integrate(2)
print ode_solver.t, ode_solver.y
```

Throws

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "continue.py", line 9, in <module>
    ode_solver.integrate(2)
  File "~/Applications/miniconda2/envs/cooperativity/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ode.py", line 408, in integrate
    self.f_params, self.jac_params)
  File "~/Applications/miniconda2/envs/cooperativity/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ode.py", line 852, in run
    self.check_handle()
  File "~/Applications/miniconda2/envs/cooperativity/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ode.py", line 651, in check_handle
    raise IntegratorConcurrencyError(self.__class__.__name__)
scipy.integrate._ode.IntegratorConcurrencyError: Integrator `vode` can be used to solve only a single problem at a time. If you want to integrate multiple problems, consider using a different integrator (see `ode.set_integrator`)
```

Comment: Note that unless you need butterfly-effect-proof reproducibility of the results, it should suffice to store the time and state (`ode_solver.t`, `ode_solver.y`) of the integrator (and your `rhs`). The only thing this does not store are internal parameters of the solver such as the integration time step, which will be automatically recalibrated when you start a new solver.

Comment: thanks @Wrzlprmft, I started persisting only time and state variables. this did not work to my satisfaction, becuase the ode system I am trying to solve is tracking the membrane potential of a neuron, odes, which can be very stiff. Just reinitializing the solver sometimes lead to quasi-freezing, because the solver had problems to find the right time step, so I chose to persist the whole solver with its complete internal state

Comment: It's hard to tell from your error summary whether it's having problems loading, or problems doing the `integrate` on the successfully loaded solver.

Comment: thanks, I added the full traceback, which shows that it successfully loads the solver, but crashes when integrating.

Answer (score 0):

SciPy’s `ode` uses compiled integrators that need to be initialised “outside” of Python and whose state (outside an integration step) is not completely reflected by what is stored on the Python side. Thus when you pickle and unpickle a solver instance, the initialisation and internal state of the compiled solver instance are lost. In case of `dopri5` and `dop853`, there appears to be nothing to store (which makes sense given that these are essentially simple Runge–Kutta solvers), but this does not hold for `vode` and `lsoda`. Hence your problems.

What may work for you is to store the internal state of the solver as far as accessible by Python (in particular, the step size).

Comment: Internal step size is available in the backend fortran code http://www.netlib.org/ode/vode.f HU and HCUR, but checking the scipy ode instance I did not find a way to access them, only a possibility to set the first step size in initialising the solver.. Any idea, how to get the internal step size?

Comment: @p.py: If it’s only in Fortran, you cannot access it from Python, unless there is already an interface this variable too Python or you write it yourself.